# In Cocoa, how do you hide a window when the application launches?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Specifically, I want to create a new NSWindow in IB in MainMenu.xib, but I don't want that to be open when the application launches. I tried doing close: and orderOut: in both the init and awakeFromNib methods of my NSWindowController class, but it flickers for a second before closing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's controlled by the "Visible at launch time" checkbox in the window inspector in interface builder.

See: [The Nib Object Life Cycle](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html).

Answer (score 6):

Open Window Attributes in IB and uncheck "Visible at launch"

Comment: Damn, I thought I had tried that, whereby thought I mean I definitely looked at it and checked it, possibly more than once. Maybe I had something else going on at the time.

Answer (score 5):

When working with Storyboards like me, be sure to also Uncheck the `"Is initial Controller"` Checkbox at the `"Window Controller Attributes"` tab. Because that Checkbox will cause the Window to always display and Ignore the `"Visible at launch"` Checkbox.

[image: Window Controller Attributes]

Answer (score 2):

open IB and uncheck "Visible at launch"

Then, use the following code in order to show it:

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just uncheck the "Visible at launch" option.